# Redirect but keep the domain the same

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I have an owncloud server, and I would like to setup a second short domain, to keep the shared links short.

lets say we've the longdomain.com and short.com
Heres is my httpd lines

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@adderss.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir/public_html
    ServerName short.com
    ServerAlias www.short.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,12})$ https://www.long.domain.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1 [QSA,L]
    ErrorLog /var/www/dir/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

With the current lines, short.com redirects to exactly where I need, but I would like this redirect to be on the background and keep the short domain on the user's browser.
How can I do this?

Update:

with this in my short domain virtual host I can visit my owncloud using the short domain.
For example: short.com/index.php/apps/files/

the long domain is vanished. I think Im one step forward now.

```
ProxyPass / https://www.long.domain.com
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.long.domain.com
```

The next step is to use the the regex so I can load only shorty id links.

How can I combine the rewrite regex above with the proxypass. 
I've tried ProxyPassMatch butI havent figured out how to use it properly
Any ideas?

Comment: You'd need to setup `mod_proxy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't make the same content addressable by short.com, short.com can proxy to the long domain by loading mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http, and changing your rewrite flag from R to P.

Comment: ProxyPassReverse / https://www.long.domain.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1
ProxyPassMatch ^/([A-Za-z0-9]{4,12})$ https://www.long.domain.com/public.php?service=shorty_relay&id=$1                      I remove the Rewrite lines and added those, but it doesnt works? I have no I idea how to use mod_prxy, to be honest, Im just trying to figure out how to do it by searching examples on the internet

Comment: This is the example I found but it seems to be all greek to me: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_apache_as_a_reverse_proxy.html